# I have an isssue while executing 8086 assembly code on masm

Tags: assembly, x86-16

The error happens during the linking part
LINK: WARNING L4021:no Stack Segment

> fatal error L1103 , attempt to access data outside segment bounds pos:76 Record Type : 8A

This is the code i used:

```
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment
STRING1 DB 08h,14h,05h,0Fh,09h
res db ?
data ends
code segment
start: mov ax, data
mov ds,ax
mov cx,04h
mov bl,00h
LEA SI,STRING1
up:
mov al,[SI]
cmp al,bl
jl nxt
mov bl,al
nxt:
inc si
dec cx
jnz up
mov res,bl
int 3
end start
code ends
```

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0dl2.jpg)

Comment: And which line of code does the error refer to?

Comment: The error seems to be in the linking part

Comment: I don't have that particular MASM version, but it seems to assemble and link fine with `ml` and `link16` from the MASM32 package (if I add a `.model small` at the beginning). I didn't try running the resulting executable.

Comment: shouldn't `end start` be after `code ends`?

Comment: i will try to run it in a different version of masm 

thanks for the help :D

Comment: Changing end start with code ends fixed it

Comment: Thank you Michael and Pawel for the help.